# How do I get data from another file to my form1 shapelist?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form1.cs that contains

```
 List<Shape> shapeList = new List<Shape>();
 listBoxDB listBoxHist = new listBoxDB();
 public Form1()
    {
        listBoxHist.Show();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
```

I have another file called listBoxDB.cs that has a button that will take data from a listbox in listBox and store in it a string Lname that form1 uses. However I can't access my shapelist to add to the list correct due to protection level. How can I fix this?

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //load 1 line
    {
        //string s = Form1.datInfo;
        Form1.Lname = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        //Console.WriteLine(text);
        Shape Line = new Line();
        Line.loadLine();
        Form1.shapeList.Add(Line); <-- I get a protection error here.
        Invalidate();
    }
```

I am able to access Lname using this getter/setter

```
public static string Lname { get; set; }
```

How can I do the same to access my shapeList in form1 within another form?

Comment: What you try to do can be done. The question is how accessible is Shape. If Shape is not public, you'll get an error, because it doesn't make sense for a public property to expose a private type. Nobody could set a value from a location where the type cannot be accessed but the property can.

Comment: How do I know how accessible shape is? How do I set shape to be public? I have created   public class AccessList
        {
            public static List<Shape> shapeList = new List<Shape>();
        }

Comment: Right click on "Shape" and click on go to definition.

Comment: It is set as: public abstract class Shape with all of its methods and overrides set as public also.

Comment: Please post the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be the difference between static and instance variables.

If you make `Lname` `static`, like this `public static string Lname { get; set; }`, then you can access it via `Form1.Lname`, but it effectively becomes a globally defined variable. If you create two instances of `Form1` they would both share the same `Lname` and that isn't usually what you should do.

Instead what you should do is declare it as `public string Lname { get; set; }` and then you could make a `SetForm1` method on your `listBoxDB` form to pass the reference to the instance of `Form1` in so that you can access `Form1`'s `public` variables from `listBoxDB`.

Your code could then look something like this:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public string Lname { get; set; }
    public List<Shape> shapeList = new List<Shape>();
    private listBoxDB listBoxHist = new listBoxDB();

    public Form1()
    {
        listBoxHist.SetForm1(this);
        listBoxHist.Show();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}

public class listBoxDB : Form
{
    private Form1 _form1 = null;

    public void SetForm1(Form1 form1)
    {
        _form1 = form1;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //load 1 line
    {
        //string s = Form1.datInfo;
        _form1.Lname = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        //Console.WriteLine(text);
        Shape Line = new Line();
        Line.loadLine();
        _form1.shapeList.Add(Line);
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you everything works once I modified it a little bit. I learned a lot from this post

Comment: @Vince - Thanks. You should up-vote and accept as answer then. :-)